# Are there any inherent problems with deep nesting of arrays/objects?

Tags: javascript

I'm working with a 2d js library.

I directories of images.
Each image is an object with properties. `image{name: "pic001.png", id: "pic001}`
Images are classified as one of 3 different types, lets say `dog`, `butt`, `lamp`.
There will be several collection objects.

Basically I'm looking at something like `foo = collection[2].dog[7].id`

Mostly, these will be referred to with batch/array tools, so keeping them collected will simplify that.

The question is this: Aside from my ability to keep things straight for myself, is there any inherent problem with relatively deep nesting like this?

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't seem like the hierarchy is too deep.

If I had to look at a lot of code like

```
foo = collection[2].dog[7].id;
```

I might go a little nuts, because I don't remember what 2 or 7 means. If that's what your code is starting to look like, you can add some enum-like object literals, and you future, maintaining-this-code self will thank you.

```
const collectionTypes = {
    dogs: 1,
    cats: 2
};
const dogTypes = {
    poodles: 7
};

foo = collection[collectionTypes.cats].dog[dogTypes.poodles].id;
```

Comment: If I were going to be looking at it yeah that makes tons of sense, but they're by and large going to be thought of no deeper than `collection`, and even they will mainly be targets of `for` and `forEach` types of iterations. Thanks.